# Project set up for JavaFX Scenic View

Tags: java, css, eclipse, javafx

I want to inspect the scene graph of my JavaFX application. 
I've downloaded ScenicView.jar and placed in my project folder along side the .fxml and .java files (I'm using Eclipse).

In VM arguments I have -javaagent:C:\path\to\bin\application\scenicview.jar

Whenever I run the Main class I get this error:

```
Platform running
Launching ScenicView v9.0.0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2459)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at org.scenicview.view.tabs.CSSFXTab.createTabContent(CSSFXTab.java:62)
    at org.scenicview.view.tabs.CSSFXTab.<init>(CSSFXTab.java:54)
    at org.scenicview.view.ScenicViewGui.buildUI(ScenicViewGui.java:300)
    at org.scenicview.view.ScenicViewGui.<init>(ScenicViewGui.java:214)
    at org.scenicview.ScenicView.start(ScenicView.java:182)
    at org.scenicview.ScenicView.lambda$premain$0(ScenicView.java:124)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Startup done
Creating server
Server done
Number of running Java applications found: 4
Obtaining properties for Java application with PID:8208
Obtaining properties for Java application with PID:12132
Error while obtaining properties for JVM:sun.tools.attach.AttachProviderImpl@3a5a5f11: 2572 application.GUI
java.io.IOException: Can not attach to current VM
    at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.HotSpotVirtualMachine.<init>(HotSpotVirtualMachine.java:75)
    at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachineImpl.<init>(VirtualMachineImpl.java:48)
    at jdk.attach/sun.tools.attach.AttachProviderImpl.attachVirtualMachine(AttachProviderImpl.java:69)
    at jdk.attach/com.sun.tools.attach.spi.AttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(AttachProvider.java:193)
    at jdk.attach/com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:249)
    at org.fxconnector.remote.RemoteConnectorImpl.getRunningJavaFXApplications(RemoteConnectorImpl.java:368)
    at org.fxconnector.remote.RemoteConnectorImpl.connect(RemoteConnectorImpl.java:251)
    at org.scenicview.model.update.RemoteVMsUpdateStrategy.getActiveApps(RemoteVMsUpdateStrategy.java:57)
    at org.scenicview.model.update.RemoteVMsUpdateStrategy.work(RemoteVMsUpdateStrategy.java:77)
    at org.fxconnector.helper.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:43)
Obtaining properties for Java application with PID:8636
1 JavaFX applications found
Loading agent from: C:\Users\Ed\workspace\ModelFX\bin\application\scenicview.jar
Loading agent for:sun.tools.attach.AttachProviderImpl@3a5a5f11: 12132 ID:12132 on port:7566 took:107ms using agent defined in C:\Users\Ed\workspace\ModelFX\bin\application\scenicview.jar
Remote agent started on port:7566
RemoteApp connected on:7558 stageID:StageID [appID=12132, stageID=1986442457, name=null]
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.scenicview.view.tabs.CSSFXTab.setActiveStage(CSSFXTab.java:112)
    at org.scenicview.view.ScenicViewGui.setActiveStage(ScenicViewGui.java:736)
    at org.scenicview.model.update.AppsRepository.lambda$appAdded$3(AppsRepository.java:97)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

I am guessing it can't read the FXML file being loaded in my code? In various controller classes I have something like this:

```
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("file.fxml"));
        loader.setController(this);
        Parent root = loader.load();
```

I really don't get this one, it's not giving much away!

EDIT: I should mention, without the VM arguments the program runs as expected. The error only appears when I try to load Scenic View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem just a second ago.
Fall back to Scenic View v8.7.0. Add it as a library.
Add `ScenicView.show(scene);` in your code and it should launch.
Note that you'll need your current project JRE and JDK8 installed.